# Fourier Integral funny notation

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

If $f$ is differentiable and $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|dx<\infty$ show that $\widehat{(f'_c)}(\omega)=\omega\hat{f_s}(w)$ and $\widehat{(f'_s)}(\omega)=-\omega\hat{f_c}(w)$

$f(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty A(\omega)\cos(\omega x)+B(\omega)\sin(\omega x)d\omega$

$A(\omega):=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(v)\cos(\omega v)dv$

$B(\omega):=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(v)\sin(\omega v)dv$

$\hat{f_c}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int\limits_0^\infty f(v)\cos(\omega v)dv$

$\hat{f_s}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int\limits_0^\infty f(v)\sin(\omega v)dv$

All these definitions to give context.  Obviously this is a homework question, but I am not seeking the answer [unless you can't help it ;)   ]. Really what I am not understanding is this notation $\widehat{(f'_c)}(\omega)$, what does this mean? I'm sure I can prove this once I know that.

Comment: Your definitions actually **do** contain the explanation for $\hat{}$; as for $\widehat{...}$, it is just another way to write the same symbol.

Comment: so basically $\widehat{(f_c')}(\omega)$ is the same as $(\hat{f}_c(w))'$?

Comment: Not quite. First the derivative, then the hat. Order does matter.

Comment: so $\hat{f}_c(f'(\omega))$?

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Why would you have a function of function, where did that come from?

Comment: I've seen functions of functions many times $f\circ g$

Comment: I think I see now though... Maybe... He means to replace $f(v)$ in $\hat{f}_c(\omega)$ by $f'$

Comment: Sure enough, you may have $f\circ g$ elsewhere. I mean, why here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your definitions actually do contain the explanation for $\hat{\circ}$; as for $\widehat{\circ\circ}$, it is just another way to write the same symbol. –  Ivan Neretin

You have: $\quad\widehat {f_c}(\omega)\mathop{:=}\sqrt{\tfrac 2\pi\;}\int\limits_{0}^\infty f(\nu)\cos(\nu\omega)\operatorname d \nu$

Then: $\qquad$ $
\widehat{f'_c}(\omega) = \sqrt{\tfrac 2 \pi \;} \int\limits_{0}^\infty f'(\nu) \cos(\nu\omega)\operatorname d \nu
\\[3ex]
\widehat{f_c}'(\omega) = \dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d \omega} \left(\sqrt{\tfrac 2 \pi \;} \int\limits_{0}^\infty f(\nu) \cos(\nu\omega)\operatorname d \nu\right)$